# Accessing object on TabItem in Silverlight, C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, tabitem

I have a tab control with a chart on it.

How can I access the chart on the tabitem to give it a datasource?

Answer (score 0):

Just use binding on the chart also set RelativeSource Ancestor to your DataContext

Comment: Currently the chart lies on a layout that gets set in Application.xaml and this is how I get hold of the tabItem

tab = sidePanel.Items[i] as TabItem;
                            if (tab.Name == customTabName)

Answer (score 0):

At first, add `using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;` and `using System.Linq;` to your usings section.

Afterwards you can get the Chart (if that's the class name) as follows:

```
Chart myChart = tab.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<Chart>().FirstOrDefault();
```